# Compile Error: itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) cannot find symbol

Tags: java, swing, jframe, awt, itemlistener

I'm attempting to create a program that uses the JFrame class. The program is supposed to use a JComboBox and a JTextField object. When the user selects a different city from the combo box, the program is supposed to change the value of the JTextField to the population of the new city that is selected.

I'm receiving an error when compiling the program that I can't quite figure out. On line 37, 'public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e);', I'm receiving an error that states "cannot find symbol". I've tried comparing my code to other code, and I can't seem to spot a difference and figure out why the compiler is returning this specific error. Any help is much appreciated, thanks!

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;

public class JPopulation extends JFrame implements ItemListener
{
   JLabel intro = new JLabel("Please Select a City");
   String[] cityList = {"Los Angeles", "San Diego", "Phoenix", "Houston", "Detroit", "Chicago", "New York City"};
   String[] cityPopValues = {"12 Million", "6 Million", "5 Million", "4 Million", "Population 0", "7  Million", "10 Million"};
   JComboBox listOfCities = new JComboBox(cityList);
   JTextField cityPop = new JTextField(cityPopValues[0], 10);
   FlowLayout flow = new FlowLayout();

   public JPopulation()
   {
      super("Find the Population of Your City");
      final int WIDTH = 300;
      final int HEIGHT = 125;
      final int X_POS = 960 - (WIDTH / 2);
      final int Y_POS = 540 - (HEIGHT / 2);

      setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
      setLocation(X_POS, Y_POS);
      setLayout(flow);
      setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

      add(intro);
      add(listOfCities);
      add(cityPop);

      cityPop.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);

      listOfCities.addItemListener(this);

   }
```

I'm receiving an error on the line directly under this text

```
   public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e)
   {
      int currentCity = listOfCities.getSelectedIndex();
      cityPop.setText(cityPopValues[currentCity]);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      JPopulation main = new JPopulation();
      main.setVisible(true);
   }
}
```

Comment: Add `import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;` to you imports

Comment: That did the trick. Thanks!